# Matching a column entry with the entry of a specific selection of columns

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe of which a part looks as follows:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
"round1 round2  round3  round4  round5  round6 a
8   12  18  32  40  36  32
6   12  18  24  30  36  30
8   16  18  24  30  36  18
4   12  12  24  30  36  24
6   16  24  32  40  48  24
8   12  18  24  30  36  30
8   12  18  24  30  36  18
8   16  24  32  40  48  40
8   16  24  24  30  48  48",
  header = TRUE
)
```

I would like to make column called `x`, which simply selects the round equal to the entry in `a`. I tried to following, but the syntax is somehow not right.

```
for (i in df$a){ 
    if (df$a[i] = df$round2[i]){
        df$x[i] = 1
    } ifelse (df$a[i] = df$round3[i]){
        df$x[i] = 2
    } ifelse (df$a[i] = df$round4[i]){
        df$x[i] = 3
    } ifelse (df$a[i] = df$round5[i]){
        df$x[i] = 4
    } ifelse (df$a[i] = df$round6[i]){
        df$x[i] = 5
    } ifelse (df$a[i] = df$round7[i]){
        df$x[i] = 6
    } 
}
```

Desired output:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- fread(
"round2 round3  round4  round5  round6  round7 a x 
8   12  18  32  40  36  32  4
6   12  18  24  30  36  30  5
8   16  18  24  30  36  18  3
4   12  12  24  30  36  24  4
6   16  24  32  40  48  24  3
8   12  18  24  30  36  30  5
8   12  18  24  30  36  18  3
8   16  24  32  40  48  40  5
8   16  24  24  30  48  48  6",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `df` with `a` values and then use `max.col` by specifying `ties.method` as `"first"`

```
max.col(df == df$a, ties.method = "first")
#[1] 4 5 3 4 3 5 3 5 6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain to me a little how this works? I have to incorporate it into a much bigger dataset, which probably requires some amendments.

Comment: @Tom Check output of `df == df$a` it returns a matrix of `TRUE`/`FALSE` where `TRUE` means the value is matched with `a` and using `max.col` we get first `TRUE` value for each row. Also notice that all values in column `df$a` is `TRUE` but here it does not matter since column `a` is after all the `round` columns and our `ties.method` is `"first"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I tried to do: `max.col(df[1:6] == df$a, ties.method = "first")` because I need to limit the columns to which the code applies, but it gives the following error:
`Error in matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent` Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what it could be but since you have a `data.table` you maybe are looking for `max.col(df[, 1:6] == df$a, ties.method = "first")`. Also can you run this on small subset of your data say 10 rows and see if you get your expected output?

Comment: I made a syntax error in referring to the correct df. It works. Thank you for your patience!